# Can't change 'name' attribute of the element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, element

Here is quite simplified version of my problem:

**What do i have:**

`<td id='cell'><input name="elem_1_Name"/></td>`

**What do i want:**

`<td id='cell'><input name="elem_1_Name"/><input name="elem_5_Name"/></td>`

**What i've tried:**

`var elem = document.getElementById("cell").lastChild.cloneNode(true);`

*and then:*

`elem.name = elem.name.replace("1","5");`

*or*

`elem.name = "elem_5_Name";`

*or*

`elem.setAttribute("name","elem_5_Name");`

*and at last*

`document.getElementById("cell").appendChild(elem);`

**what did I get while debugging:**

`elem.name :  "elem_5_Name"`

**!!but!!**

`document.getElementById("cell").innerHTML : <input name="elem_1_Name"/><input name="elem_1_Name"/>`

When i try to set innerHTML directly - i have IE unknown runtime error

Comment: Your first attempt (using `replace`) works for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/UDuBT/

Comment: Works for me in Chrome and IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/42LHk/

Comment: All of them work for me on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/ffaQn/

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("cell").innerHTML : <input name="elem_1_Name"/><input name="elem_1_Name"/>`
should be:
`document.getElementById("cell").innerHTML='<input name="elem_1_Name"/><input name="elem_5_Name"/>';`

This works crossbrowser (tested in IE6).

As Bergi pointed out, the folloing code should also work (tested in IE6 and FF12).
It uses conditional comments to target microsoft's jscript (thus IE):

```
/*@cc_on @if (@_jscript)
var elem = document.createElement('<input name="elem_5_Name">');
@else */
var elem = document.createElement("input");
elem.name = "elem_5_Name";
/* @end @*/

document.getElementById("cell").appendChild(elem);
```

Good Luck!!

Comment: I guess that is only his debugging: Reading the property gives …

Comment: @Bergi: the asker states: `When i try to set innerHTML directly - i have IE unknown runtime error`. Every browser should choke on this naturally.

Answer (score 1):

The [`name` attribute/property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms534184) is quirksy in early IE versions. See

- http://javascript.about.com/library/bliebug2.htm
- http://thunderguy.com/semicolon/2005/05/23/setting-the-name-attribute-in-internet-explorer/

(from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711100/1048572))